# Cant debug react-native app in release mode within android studio(Graddle debuggle error)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Required configurations done as seen below;
(AndroidManifest.xml doest **NOT** contains  android:debuggable="true" since its added by AS automatically)

After I click "Debug App" icon in AS, this is the error show up;
[image: trivieRelease]

It claims graddle not contains debuggable attributes which already there.. I tried Clean Project. rebuild app via yarn bundle:android,

Build Variants(it works fine if its change to 'debug');

[image]

build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {}
        release {
            debuggable true
            productFlavors.myapp.signingConfig signingConfigs.myappRelease
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro" 
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="${appIcon}"
        android:roundIcon="${appIconRound}"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

what should be missing here?